# How to get the height or width of a WPF element which depends on the parent element

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas that automatically resizes to it's parent element (grid column). Because i want to add a border, I essentially just want to add 4 lines to the canvas which would represent this border.

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas_main" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

to add the lines I write for example:

```
Line right = new Line();
right.StrokeThickness = 1;
right.X1 = canvas_main.Width;
right.Y1 = 0;
right.X2 = canvas_main.Width;
right.Y2 = canvas_main.Height;
right.Stroke = brush;
canvas_main.Children.Add(right);
```

When running this I get an error: System.ArgumentsException saying "NaN" is not a valid value for the coordinates. The function that initializes the border lines comes after the  InitializeComponent(); function.

How can I keep the canvas auto re-sizable but also get the width/height for the border lines ?

Comment: What if you use the ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties of the Canvas?

Comment: @erik, why not `<Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="20"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"> <Canvas x:Name="canvas_main"/> </Border>`? a border can be outside

Comment: @mm8 yes, this fixed it. I mean i don't get the error anymore, but the lines don't show anymore. They do show when i just use a hard-coded width and height.

Comment: What's the value of the ActualWidth property at runtime when you add the Line?

Comment: @ASh yes thank you, this does exactly what i want! i also needed to add BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" though

Comment: @ASh this odes not however solve the problem of using its values at runtime to add elements in specific spots.

Comment: @erik, I'm not sure which elements you mean. If you made a `Border` around canvas, you don't need `Line right`, `Line left`, etc anymore. Also even if canvas real size is [ActualWidth, ActualHeight], you *can* add elements with larger x,y values (they will not be visible on the screen however)

Comment: @ASh, well i mean, i want to use the canvas to add elements of course. To give the element a position i would like to use the height and width of the canvas.